# How can I perform Acumatica BQL JOINs in PXSelector?

Tags: c#, sql, join, selector, acumatica

I have a Selector field where I want to show 5 columns from 3 different table. They are
The Item, item desctiption, item class, item class description and the default warehouse.
I have found the DACs and the fields.

InventoryItem.inventoryID;

InventoryItem.descr;

INItemClass.itemClassID;

INItemClass.descr;

INItemSite.siteID;

I have also written the [PXSelector] attribute containing the JOIN.

```
    #region Field of Me
    public abstract class fieldOfMe : BqlString.Field<fieldOfMe> { }

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Field Of Me")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(
        Search2<InventoryItem.inventoryID,
            LeftJoin<INItemClass,
                On<INItemClass.itemClassID, Equal<InventoryItem.itemClassID>>,
                LeftJoin<INItemSite,
                    On<INItemSite.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.dfltSiteID>>>>>),
          typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
          typeof(InventoryItem.descr),
          typeof(INItemClass.itemClassCD),
          typeof(INItemClass.descr),
          typeof(INItemSite.siteID),
          ValidateValue = false
        )]
    public string FieldOfMe { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

This is the screen.

[image: Screenshot of the field]

I want to learn the way I can find the default Warehouse. How can I edit the code to see the active warehouse name? I want the one with checkbox.

[image: Warehouses]

I have done the biggest part of the task but I still need some help to finish this.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your select query to do what you want.

Note that in later versions of Acumatica the dfltSiteID field in InventoryItem table will become obsolete and removed. InventoryItemCurySettings.dfltSiteID should be used instead. I have added a second query to demonstrate the use of InventoryItemCurySettings.

```
#region Field of Me
    public abstract class fieldOfMe : BqlString.Field<fieldOfMe> { }

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Field Of Me")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(
        Search2<InventoryItem.inventoryID,
            InnerJoin<INItemClass,
                On<INItemClass.itemClassID, Equal<InventoryItem.itemClassID>>,
            LeftJoin<INSite,
                On<InventoryItem.dfltSiteID, Equal<INSite.siteID>>>>>),
          typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
          typeof(InventoryItem.descr),
          typeof(INItemClass.itemClassCD),
          typeof(INItemClass.descr),
          typeof(INSite.siteCD),
          ValidateValue = false
        )]
    public string FieldOfMe { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

Using InventoryItemCurySettings.dfltSiteID

```
#region Field of Me2
    public abstract class fieldOfMe2 : BqlString.Field<fieldOfMe2> { }

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Field Of Me2")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(
        Search2<InventoryItem.inventoryID,
            InnerJoin<INItemClass,
                On<InventoryItem.itemClassID, Equal<INItemClass.itemClassID>>,
            LeftJoin<InventoryItemCurySettings, 
                On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItemCurySettings.inventoryID>,
                    And<InventoryItemCurySettings.curyID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.baseCuryID>>>>,
            LeftJoin<INSite,
                On<InventoryItemCurySettings.dfltSiteID, Equal<INSite.siteID>>>>>>),
          typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
          typeof(InventoryItem.descr),
          typeof(INItemClass.itemClassCD),
          typeof(INItemClass.descr),
          typeof(INSite.siteCD),
          ValidateValue = false
        )]
    public string FieldOfMe2 { get; set; }
    #endregion
```